# creating lists from row data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My *input* data has the following format

```
id  offset  code
 1      3    21
 1      3    24
 1      5    21
 2      1    84
 3      5    57
 3      5    21
 3      5    92
 3     10    83
 3     10    21
```

I would like the *output* in the following format

```
id   offset                   code
 1    [3,5]         [[21,24],[21]]
 2      [1]                 [[84]]
 3   [5,10]   [[21,57,92],[21,83]]
```

The code that I have been able to come up with is shown below

```
import random, pandas
random.seed(10000)

param = dict(nrow=100, nid=10, noffset=8, ncode=100)
#param = dict(nrow=1000, nid=10, noffset=8, ncode=100)
#param = dict(nrow=100000, nid=1000, noffset=50, ncode=5000)
#param = dict(nrow=10000000, nid=10000, noffset=100, ncode=5000)

pd = pandas.DataFrame({
    "id":random.choices(range(1,param["nid"]+1), k=param["nrow"]), 
    "offset":random.choices(range(param["noffset"]), k=param["nrow"])
})
pd["code"] = random.choices(range(param["ncode"]), k=param["nrow"])
pd = pd.sort_values(["id","offset","code"]).reset_index(drop=True)

tmp1 = pd.groupby(by=["id"])["offset"].apply(lambda x:list(set(x))).reset_index()
tmp2 = pd.groupby(by=["id","offset"])["code"].apply(lambda x:list(x)).reset_index().groupby(\
    by=["id"], sort=True)["code"].apply(lambda x:list(x)).reset_index()

out = pandas.merge(tmp1, tmp2, on="id", sort=False)
```

It does give me the output that I want but is VERY slow when the dataframe is large.  The dataframe that I have has over 40million rows.  In the example 
 uncomment the fourth param statement and you will see how slow it is.

Can you please help with making this run faster?

Comment: For 40m rows, this may not be a appropriate data structure, what is the usecase that needs nested lists? Any further aggregations on the output would be even slower.

Answer (score 5):

```
(df.groupby(['id','offset']).code.apply(list).reset_index()
   .groupby('id').agg(lambda x: x.tolist()))
Out[733]: 
     offset                      code
id                                   
1    [3, 5]          [[21, 24], [21]]
2       [1]                    [[84]]
3   [5, 10]  [[57, 21, 92], [83, 21]]
```